# ILMerge - ignore dependency

Tags: .net, oracle, merge, odp.net, ilmerge

I am using ILMerge to bundle dependencies for an exe that I've created into a single exe.  I've run into a problem where one of my dependencies relies on Oracle.DataAccess.dll, which has different versions for 32 and 64 bit.  I bundled the 32-bit version into my output executable, but it errors when run on a 64-bit machine.  Is there a way for me to wrap all my dependencies EXCEPT the Oracle one through ILMerge, thus forcing the executable to search for it at runtime?  This would allow me to swap the 32 and 64 bit dlls in as needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to only merge a subset of dependencies using ILMerge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509344/is-it-possible-to-only-merge-a-subset-of-dependencies-using-ilmerge)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this wasn't actually a problem.  Earlier I had included the Oracle.DataAccess dll explicitly to resolve another issue.  Removing this from the ILMerge build event took care of the issue.